# libGDX - My script takes a really long time to process my copy method

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx, tiled

So right now I am copying tiles that are within the camera's viewport, and pasting them to the top of the TiledMap using the following function:

```
    public TiledMapTile[][] copyRegion(TiledMapTileLayer layer, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    TiledMapTile[][] region = new TiledMapTile[width][height];

    for (int ix = x; ix < x + width; ix++)
        for (int iy = y; iy < y + height; iy++) {
            Cell cell = layer.getCell(ix, iy);
            if(cell == null)
                continue;

            region[ix - x][iy - y] = cell.getTile();

        }

    return region;
}
```

My problem is with this double for loop, its searching through each x and y value of the viewport, which is thousands of loops which is obviously my problem. Before this I was setting the width and height to the TiledMapTileLayer's layer.getTileHeight and layer.getTileWidth and it ran smoothly. This is because the layers x and y values go by the Tiles, so it was only really checking about 100 tiles, which is much faster. How would I go about "merging" the 2 together to only copy the tiles within the viewport, instead of the x and y values within the viewport?

I am calling this function using the following:

```
clipboard = TileMapCopier.copyRegion(layer, 0, 0, (int) camera.viewportWidth, (int) camera.viewportHeight);
TileMapCopier.pasteRegion(layer, clipboard, 0, layer.getHeight() / 2);
```

Thanks!

EDIT: I was told to look at how the orthogonal tiled map renderer renders based on viewport. I dont really know how to do this :P Im still new to this.

```
    @Override
public void renderTileLayer (TiledMapTileLayer layer) {
    final Color batchColor = spriteBatch.getColor();
    final float color = Color.toFloatBits(batchColor.r, batchColor.g, batchColor.b, batchColor.a * layer.getOpacity());

    final int layerWidth = layer.getWidth();
    final int layerHeight = layer.getHeight();

    final float layerTileWidth = layer.getTileWidth() * unitScale;
    final float layerTileHeight = layer.getTileHeight() * unitScale;

    final int col1 = Math.max(0, (int)(viewBounds.x / layerTileWidth));
    final int col2 = Math.min(layerWidth, (int)((viewBounds.x + viewBounds.width + layerTileWidth) / layerTileWidth));

    final int row1 = Math.max(0, (int)(viewBounds.y / layerTileHeight));
    final int row2 = Math.min(layerHeight, (int)((viewBounds.y + viewBounds.height + layerTileHeight) / layerTileHeight));

    float y = row1 * layerTileHeight;
    float xStart = col1 * layerTileWidth;
    final float[] vertices = this.vertices;

    for (int row = row1; row < row2; row++) {
        float x = xStart;
        for (int col = col1; col < col2; col++) {
            final TiledMapTileLayer.Cell cell = layer.getCell(col, row);
            if (cell == null) {
                x += layerTileWidth;
                continue;
            }
            final TiledMapTile tile = cell.getTile();

            if (tile != null) {
                final boolean flipX = cell.getFlipHorizontally();
                final boolean flipY = cell.getFlipVertically();
                final int rotations = cell.getRotation();

                TextureRegion region = tile.getTextureRegion();

                float x1 = x;
                float y1 = y;
                float x2 = x1 + region.getRegionWidth() * unitScale;
                float y2 = y1 + region.getRegionHeight() * unitScale;

                float u1 = region.getU();
                float v1 = region.getV2();
                float u2 = region.getU2();
                float v2 = region.getV();

                vertices[X1] = x1;
                vertices[Y1] = y1;
                vertices[C1] = color;
                vertices[U1] = u1;
                vertices[V1] = v1;

                vertices[X2] = x1;
                vertices[Y2] = y2;
                vertices[C2] = color;
                vertices[U2] = u1;
                vertices[V2] = v2;

                vertices[X3] = x2;
                vertices[Y3] = y2;
                vertices[C3] = color;
                vertices[U3] = u2;
                vertices[V3] = v2;

                vertices[X4] = x2;
                vertices[Y4] = y1;
                vertices[C4] = color;
                vertices[U4] = u2;
                vertices[V4] = v1;

                if (flipX) {
                    float temp = vertices[U1];
                    vertices[U1] = vertices[U3];
                    vertices[U3] = temp;
                    temp = vertices[U2];
                    vertices[U2] = vertices[U4];
                    vertices[U4] = temp;
                }
                if (flipY) {
                    float temp = vertices[V1];
                    vertices[V1] = vertices[V3];
                    vertices[V3] = temp;
                    temp = vertices[V2];
                    vertices[V2] = vertices[V4];
                    vertices[V4] = temp;
                }
                if (rotations != 0) {
                    switch (rotations) {
                    case Cell.ROTATE_90: {
                        float tempV = vertices[V1];
                        vertices[V1] = vertices[V2];
                        vertices[V2] = vertices[V3];
                        vertices[V3] = vertices[V4];
                        vertices[V4] = tempV;

                        float tempU = vertices[U1];
                        vertices[U1] = vertices[U2];
                        vertices[U2] = vertices[U3];
                        vertices[U3] = vertices[U4];
                        vertices[U4] = tempU;
                        break;
                    }
                    case Cell.ROTATE_180: {
                        float tempU = vertices[U1];
                        vertices[U1] = vertices[U3];
                        vertices[U3] = tempU;
                        tempU = vertices[U2];
                        vertices[U2] = vertices[U4];
                        vertices[U4] = tempU;
                        float tempV = vertices[V1];
                        vertices[V1] = vertices[V3];
                        vertices[V3] = tempV;
                        tempV = vertices[V2];
                        vertices[V2] = vertices[V4];
                        vertices[V4] = tempV;
                        break;
                    }
                    case Cell.ROTATE_270: {
                        float tempV = vertices[V1];
                        vertices[V1] = vertices[V4];
                        vertices[V4] = vertices[V3];
                        vertices[V3] = vertices[V2];
                        vertices[V2] = tempV;

                        float tempU = vertices[U1];
                        vertices[U1] = vertices[U4];
                        vertices[U4] = vertices[U3];
                        vertices[U3] = vertices[U2];
                        vertices[U2] = tempU;
                        break;
                    }
                    }
                }
                spriteBatch.draw(region.getTexture(), vertices, 0, 20);
            }
            x += layerTileWidth;
        }
        y += layerTileHeight;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I'd look at how the OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer calculates what to draw based on the viewport and adapt that to your needs.

Comment: I'm pretty new to this stuff, so I dont really understand how to do that :/ Ive been stuck on this for days now :P I posted up the tiledmaprenderer for reference

Comment: You want to look at the calculation of col1,col2,row1,row2. The viewBounds rectangle is set to the viewport. When deciding what to draw, the position and size, along with the tile size (scaled by unit scale) are used to pick only the tiles which would be drawn. You'll want to do the same calculation and loop, but instead of drawing the tiles, you'll copy them.